# IF or boolean Statements within c

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

I have been stuck with a problem for a while. I'm trying to code which allows the user to input a value and if two of the values are the same then an output of "It's a perfect square" should be displayed but if three values are displayed then " It's a perfect cube" should be displayed. So far I'm slightly confused as to what I have done but when I do put input values sometimes I will receive the correct answer or It will display all of my printf outputs. I cannot seem to get my head around the situation and could really use with some help in understanding. How to lay it out. Currently I'm writing in C and I'm a beginner programmer, I have included a screen shot of what I have done so far and it would be really useful if someone could tell me where I have gone wrong.

My code so far

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{

    int Height;
    int Width;
    int Depth;

    printf("Please insert value\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &Height, &Width, &Depth);

    if(Height == Width)
    {
        printf("It's a square cuboid\n");
    }
    else if(Height == Depth)
    {
        printf("It's a square cuboid\n");
    }
    else if(Width == Depth)
    {
        printf("It's a square cuboid\n");
    }
}
```

Thanks Hadleigh

Comment: All of those printf statements are the same.

Comment: You should indent your code

Comment: Since all the messages are the same: `"It's a square cuboid\n"` you can combine them by logical or `||`: `if ((Height == Width) || (Height == Depth) || (Width == Depth)) printf("It's a square cuboid\n");`

Comment: what exactly you want out of the code??
a cuboid doesnt need to have any side of same length. a rectangular cuboid needs that.. nd if all sides are same, then its a cube

Comment: Your code won't compile too. You are missing a `}` at the end

Answer (score 2):

You can chain boolean statements using the `&&` and `||` operators. For example, if you wanted to check if it was a perfect cube:

```
//If Height equals width AND height equals depth
if(Height == Width && Height == Depth)
{
    printf("Perfect Cube!");
}
```

Or if you wanted to check if it was a perfect square:

```
if(Height == Width && Depth == 0)
{
    printf("Perfect Square!");
}
```

So to put this all together, once you've verified your inputs, you just need to figure out what checks do what.

```
int Height;
int Width;
int Depth;

printf("Please insert value\n");

if(scanf("%d%d%d", &Height, &Width, &Depth) != 3)
{
    printf("Wrong number of inputs");
    return -1;
}

//this            AND  this
if(Height == Width && Depth == 0)
{
    printf("Perfect Square!");
}//     this           AND   this
else if(Height == Width && Height == Depth)
{
    printf("Perfect Cube!");
}//     This             OR  this           OR this           then...
else if (Height == Width || Height == Depth || Width == Depth)
{
    printf("Square-faced cuboid!");
}
```

Comment: it should be logical or condition not logical and.

Comment: @KhairulBasar If I'm just checking that is's a square cuboid, yeah, but for it being a cube or a square it needs to be an and.

Comment: @KhairulBasar I'm fairly confused, do you think I'm wrong, or am I reading sarcasm where it shouldn't be there? I'm pretty sure I'm right, but if you explain my mistake and you're right, I'm more than happy to learn.

Comment: actually i'm also confused...his conditions are not clear as he said, "but if three values are displayed then " It's a perfect cube" should be displayed". i didn't understand what does it mean...but, so far you are right...

Answer (score 1):

1. You should test that `scanf()` returns 3, before relying on the variables to have proper values.
2. All your `printf()` statements print the same thing, making it impossible to see if it works from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick response and I now understand how it should be laid out and it works perfectly. I just have one quick follow up question. How would I introduce multiplication into each of the if statement lines in order to time Height * Width * Depth together to get the volume. Im looking to do this for each line. I have insert a copy of my code and just want to add to it really.

```
{

int Height;
int Width;
int Depth;


scanf("%d%d%d", &Height, &Width, &Depth );

if(Height == Width && Depth >=0){
printf("It's a square cuboid\nThe volume is %d ");

}

if(Height == Depth && Width >= 0)
printf("It's a square cuboid\n ");

if(Width == Depth && Height >= 0)
printf("It's a square cuboid\n");

if(Height == Width && Height == Depth)
printf("It's a perfect cube\n ");


}
```

Thanks 
Hadleigh